# How to apply known normal to a point cloud in open3d?

Tags: python, point-clouds, surface, open3d

I have a list of 4 planar points, and I want to visualise the surface between them.
For this, I am using Poisson reconstruction in Open3d.

```
#points (X, Y, Z)
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
xyz = np.array([[36.1162223 , 22.13427368,  0.37597846],
   [36.1162223 , 22.13427368,  0.        ],
   [40.67849004, 22.13427368,  0.        ],
   [40.67849004, 22.13427368,  0.37597846]])
```

from the dataset I am generating these points, I also have the normal for this surface:

`normals = np.array([ 0., -1.,  0.])`

My question is, how to apply the normal to the point cloud in a correct manner so that the reconstruction is possible?

**Reproduce error:**

After running the above, run the following:

```
#surface reconstruction, poisson
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
pcd.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(normal)
print(pcd)
with o3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(
        o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:
    mesh, densities = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(
        pcd, depth=9)
print(mesh)
```

The error I get is:

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /Users/usrname/notes.ipynb
> Cell 15 in <cell line: 5>()
> 3 pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
> 4 pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(xyz)
> ----> 5 pcd.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(normal)
> 6 print(pcd)
> 7 with o3d.utility.VerbosityContextManager(
> 8         o3d.utility.VerbosityLevel.Debug) as cm:
>
> RuntimeError:

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to assign one normal to 4 points. The number of point normals has to equal the number of points.